# React Material UI prevent List re-render

Tags: reactjs, renderer, use-state

I am facing unneccesary re-renders in my List when i click on the expand icon.
Currently i can see in the Profiler that the whole List is re-rendered and when i tried to wrap the list inside a React memo it does not solve the issue.
Is there anything i can do to prevent the rerendering of the whole List?

The goal is to build a modular side menu with the `navigation` variable.

```js
      const navigation = [
        { id: "Überschrift", type: "header" },
        { id: "Test", icon: <StarBorder />, type: "category" },
        {
          id: "Navigation 1",
          icon: <AcUnitIcon />,
          type: "category",
          children: [
            { id: "Sent mail", icon: <InboxIcon />, active: true },
            { id: "Drafts", icon: <DraftsIcon /> },
            { id: "Inbox", icon: <SendIcon /> }
          ]
        },
      ];
```

The issue is to trigger the collapse of the parent list if one child is active.
I wrote the `updateparent` function to do so.

```js
      const updateparent = (childId, id) => {
        console.log("updateparent");
        if (childId !== openchild) {
          console.log("setstate");
          setOpenChild(childId);
          setOpen((open) => ({ ...open, ...{ [id]: true } }));
        }
        return true;
      };
```

This work ok so far now but my question is if this is the "official" way how to solve this issue.
Basically i need to use a second state ( `openchild` ) that stores the last active item when the map function loops through all children.
If i do not implement this i will end up in a contineously re render issue.

I also have a strange behaviour for the function call:

```js
<ListItem selected={ active === true ? updateparent(childId, id) : false }
```

The updateparent function is rendered two times (from the console log). Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Please have a look at the following sandbox:

[image: Edit material-demo-forked-tkctz]

Please find the simplified logic of the component below (i removed the unnecessary stuff for the question the full example is running iside the sandbox)

```js
export default function NestedList() {
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState({});
      const [openchild, setOpenChild] = React.useState({});
    
      const handleClick = (name) => {
        setOpen((open) => ({ ...open, ...{ [name]: !open[name] } }));
      };
    
      return (
        <List component="nav" className={classes.root}>
          {navigation.map(({ id, type, icon, active, children }) => {
            if (typeof children !== "undefined" && children.length > 0) {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={id}>
                  <ListItem button key={id} onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>
                    {open[id] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                  </ListItem>
                  <Collapse in={open[id]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                      {children.map(({ id: childId, icon, active }) => (
                        <ListItem
                          selected={
                            active === true ? updateparent(childId, id) : false
                          }
                        >
                        </ListItem>
                      ))}
                    </List>
                  </Collapse>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            } 
         )}
        </List>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solution is best practice, but I do this by passing a `forceUpdate` function from the parent element to the child. The simplest way to do this is by writing a reusable hook, `useForceUpdate`:

```
function useForceUpdate() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return () => setCount(val => val + 1);
}
```

And then using this hook in your parent component as such:

```
const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
```

Calling `forceUpdate` in any child components will trigger a state change in the parent component, forcing the parent to re-render. Make sure to wrap this call in a conditional or in a `useEffect` hook so that you don't trigger an infinite re-render loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i think i phrased the question rather badly. With the parent component i meant the List "above" the children. I am not sure if the `updateparent ` function is correct in the React way, or if i need to use a Hook like memo or something. And the other question is why the function is called twice and not only once because there is only one active item in the list.

Comment: Do you have a hint for me how i can solve this issue without adding an additional state and with React hooks?